# Google plus with CocoaPods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, cocoapods

In an iOS app I'm developing, I need to add Google+ sign-in feature. The app is developed in Swift.

I added the GooglePlus iOS SDK through CocoaPods. Please note that I have CocoaPods v0.36 beta installed which officially supports Swift. I've integrated many Objective-C libraries with Swift projects this way before.

The pod installation was successful. Then I needed to import the framework to files where I wanted to use its methods so I added the below lines to the top of the file.

```
import GooglePlus
import GoogleOpenSource
```

But when I build the project I get the following errors.

**No such module 'GooglePlus'**

**No such module 'GoogleOpenSource'**

What am I doing wrong here? Am I specifying the correct names?

---

**Edit:** I'm aware of using the bridging header. But the latest CocoaPods supports adding Obj-C libraries to projects. It automatically converts them to frameworks so that you could use them the Swift way. I've done it before with some other Obj-C libraries without the bridging header. It fails with Google+'s iOS SDK.

Comment: I've got almost the same behaviour when I've add the second pod 'Alamofire'. Error:failed to import bridging header

Comment: @avgx You don't need to add anything to the bridging header. I use Alamofire through CocoaPods too and it work just fine actually.

Comment: 8 months later, got any luck?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a bridging header where you'll import the Objective-C classes that you want to expose to Swift. You can see the documentation on how this works [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

The easiest way to create one is to create a Objective-C class in your project. Then Xcode will ask if you'd like to create a bridging header, just say Yes and then delete the class you created.

In this header import the necessary Google frameworks, then you'll have access to those classes in Swift.

Comment: Thanks but yes, I'm aware of using the bridging header. But the latest CocoaPods supports adding Obj-C libraries to projects. It automatically converts them to frameworks so that you could use them the Swift way. I've done it before with some other Obj-C libraries without the bridging header. Not sure why it fails with Google+'s iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, setup your application in the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).

If you want to configure using Cocoapods, you just need to produce a Podfile:

```
target 'swiftsignin' do
  pod 'googleplus-ios-sdk'
end
```

Then run `pod install` from the folder containing your project and open the generated project.xcworkspace.

If you are configuring using just the SDK, [download the Google+ SDK](http://goo.gl/9cTqyZ) and include it in your project.

The first part of this is to force the creation of a bridging header by adding an Obj-C file to your project. Within the bridging header, include the Google+ libraries:

```
// example bridging header...

#ifndef swiftsignin_Bridging_h
#define swiftsignin_Bridging_h

#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>

#endif
```

Next, somewhere in your code, e.g. the ViewController, configure the Sign-in object:

```
  // Configure the sign in object.
  var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
  signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
  signIn.clientID = kClientId
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = toggleFetchEmail.on
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = toggleFetchUserID.on
  signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
  signIn.trySilentAuthentication()
  signIn.delegate = self
```

Naturally, `kClientId` needs to be defined somewhere to point to your client ID.

In your app delegate, you will need to add an open URL handler that accepts the authorization code when the OAuth 2.0 auth steps complete and passes it to the authorization library:

```
// Added to handle the Authorization code returned from sign-in.
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

In your app info.plist, add a URL handler that has the scheme and identifier set to your app's bundle name.

I have created [a demo Google+ Sign-in Swift app on GitHub](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-ios-swift) that might be helpful for you.

Comment: Added example podfile to project