# Building a Cocoapod with Swift and dependency on Objective-C framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios, lint

I know there are already a few questions on this theme here on SO, but very few have accepted answers, and I don't think I have found the exact same problem as mine.

I'm building a Swift pod, and in my code I rely on the Google Maps iOS SDK, which is bundled as a `.framework` file. The project builds OK in Xcode, however I have troubles publishing the lib to Cocoapods.

I managed to have a `Podspec` file that almost validates using the `pod lib lint` command. However, now that I've added the `Google-Maps-iOS-SDK` pod as a dependency in the `Podspec` file, it fails with the following message:

> $ pod lib lint
>
> [!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static
> binaries:
> (/private/var/folders/n2/qyjfpk6n7zz_mngtwswlmsy00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps.framework)

> $

Is this expected? Why can't I add the Google Maps iOS SDK as a pod reference in my own Swift-based pod?

Here's the `Podspec`:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name                  = '(name)'
    s.version               = '1.0.0'
    s.summary               = '(summary)'
    s.platforms             = { :ios => '8.0', :osx => '10.10' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
    s.osx.deployment_target = '10.10'
    s.license               = { :type => 'BSD', :file => 'LICENSE' }
    s.source_files          = 'Sources/*.{h,swift}', '*.framework'
    s.source                = { :git => "https://github.com/(Github repo).git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
    s.requires_arc          = true
    s.frameworks            = "Foundation", "CoreLocation"
    s.author                = { 'Romain L' => '(email)' }
    s.dependency 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'
end
```

If I don't include the Google Maps iOS SDK as a dependency, then `pod lib lint` fails in the Bridging Header, and complains it cannot find `<GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` (file not found).

I'm stuck, and I don't know if it's a bug from Cocoapods 0.36 (still in Beta) or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found another thread on SO dealing with similar problems: [Linker errors in a Swift project with Google Maps for iOS added via CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405079/linker-errors-in-a-swift-project-with-google-maps-for-ios-added-via-cocoapods).

It appears that the errors were due to a combination of bad Podspec file (on the Google Maps iOS SDK side), and bugs in Cocoapods 0.36 Beta.

It's actually possible to workaround the issues by using @fz.'s revised Podspec file for Google Maps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28471830/145997. Another article that also was of great interest to understand how the `vendored_frameworks` setting works in `Podspec` is: http://codereaper.com/blog/2014/creating-a-pod-with-crashreporter/.

So, to correctly import the Google Maps iOS SDK in a Pod project, first use the following `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
# altered version of Google's Podspec
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', :podspec => "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Reflejo/GoogleMapsPodspec/master/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK.podspec.json"
use_frameworks! # don't forget this!
```

I'm now able to reference Google Maps classes from my Swift code simply by doing `import GoogleMaps`. And, to distribute the Pod, my final `Podspec` now resembles the following:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name                  = 'MyPod'
    s.version               = '1.0.0'

    s.homepage              = "https://github.com/..."
    s.summary               = '(pod summary)'
    #s.screenshot            = ""

    s.author                = { 'Romain L' => '(email)' }
    s.license               = { :type => 'BSD', :file => 'LICENSE' }
    s.social_media_url      = "https://twitter.com/_RomainL"
    s.platforms             = { :ios => '8.0' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

    s.source_files          = 'MyCode/*.{h,swift}'
    s.module_name           = 'MyPod'
    s.source                = { :git => "https://github.com/....git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
    s.requires_arc          = true
    s.libraries             = "c++", "icucore", "z" # required for GoogleMaps.framework
    s.frameworks            = "AVFoundation", "CoreData", "CoreLocation", "CoreText", "Foundation", "GLKit", "ImageIO", "OpenGLES", "QuartzCore", "SystemConfiguration", "GoogleMaps" # required for GoogleMaps.framework
    s.vendored_frameworks   = "Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework" # Put the Google-provided framework in that subfolder of your Pod project
    #s.dependency              'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK' # Careful! this will cause errors if enabled!
end
```

I am now able to start a new iOS app in Xcode and use the following `Podfile` to link against my own pod, itself referencing the Google Maps iOS SDK:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'MyPod'
use_frameworks! # do not forget this!
```

Not that easy, but feasible after all! Hoping Google will soon patch its `Podspec` file for Swift developments, though.

Comment: This is perfect. It helped me get Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK running on 0.38.2 just now by creating that custom-style podspec. Thanks, @Romain!

Comment: thanks! this is very helpful answer. FYI: currently, `GoogleMaps 1.12.3` needs `Accelerate.framework`.