# Building Cocoapod library with GoogleMaps SDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios, podspec

I want to use `GoogleMaps` in My Cocoapod library.

There is [GoogleMaps in cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMaps). but, you can't use `dependency` because it is static library. probably...

I referenced this answer.
[Building a Cocoapod with Swift and dependency on Objective-C framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937580/1897767)
And, building library was succeeded.

I have problem when using builded library in Example project.

When I built Example project, first problem is

> ld: framework not found GoogleMaps for architecture arm64

And, I tried to add `GoogleMaps` to Example project's `Podfile`.
next problem is

> The 'Pods-MapLibraryWrapper_Example' target has frameworks with
>   conflicting names: GoogleMaps.

Is there a way to solve the problem? or, Is there a other way to use `GoogleMaps`?

Thanks.

### Part of My library's podspec.

```
  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MapLibraryWrapper' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }
  s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'MapLibraryWrapper-ios' => 'Resources/*.png' }

  s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks = "Accelerate", "AVFoundation", "CoreData", "CoreLocation", "CoreText", "Foundation", "GLKit", "ImageIO", "OpenGLES", "QuartzCore", "SystemConfigurati\
on", "GoogleMaps"
  # s.dependency 'GoogleMaps'
  s.libraries = "c++", "icucore", "z"
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework'

  s.prepare_command = './download-googlemaps.sh'
```

### directory structure

```
$(project_root)
    |- MapLibraryWrapper.podspec
    |- Dependencies/
        |- GoogleMaps.framework
    |- Example
        |- Podfile
```

### Example/Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'MapLibraryWrapper_Example', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'MapLibraryWrapper', :path => '../'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'MapLibraryWrapper_Tests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'MapLibraryWrapper', :path => '../'

  pod 'Quick', '~> 0.8.0'
  pod 'Nimble', '3.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Please check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35174534/5872894

Comment: Thanks. I checked out it. but, `$(inherited)` is already exists in other linker flag. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8kzzb.png

Comment: Please click on arrow and check `$(inherited) ` is implemented in both (Debug and Release)

Comment: Both Debug and Release are `$(inherited)`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Posted an anwer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453410/how-to-fix-framework-with-conflicting-names-in-cocoapods/39465955#39465955